# Como adicionar valor em um array sem perder o valor anterior?

Tags: php

Através de um formulário e um único input eu preciso receber vários números e armazenar esses números em um array. Exemplo, eu digito um número qualquer no input e clico no botão submit do formulário, com o PHP eu pego esse valor e armazeno no array. Mas se fizer o mesmo processo novamente o valor anterior vai ser perdido. Como faço para não perde ele ? Tentei colocar o input como texto e passar todos os números de uma vez, mas não sei como tratar dos espaço e não é o foco utilizar Regex. Como posso fazer isso sem regex ?

Comment: A sua questão ficou meio vaga. Sugiro colocar o código que disse que já tentou e mostrar em que parte não estava a funcionar como queria.

Comment: Utilizei o explode para pegar os valores separados pelo espaço e transformar em um array.

Answer (score 1):

O aconselhável seria representando a variável como array `$array[]` e incluindo os valores:

Simples:

```
$array[] = 'aaa';
print_r($array);
// resultado: Array ( [0] => aaa )

$array[] = 'bbb';
print_r($array);
// resultado: Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => bbb )
```

Utilizando loop:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++)
{
    $array[] = $x;
}
print_r($array);
// resultado: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )
```

---

Também funciona, mas não aconselhável pois trata-se de uma função, então torna-se o processamento mais lento:

Simples:

```
$cesta = array("laranja", "morango");
array_push($cesta, "melancia", "batata");
print_r($cesta);
```

Com loop:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++)
{
    array_push($array, $x);
}
```

---

Também se tem vários outros métodos, como exemplo, um pouco mais utilizado, o `array_merge`, que une 2 ou mais arrays:

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

---

Documentações: [array_push](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php), [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)

---

Caso não responda sua pergunte, comente.

Answer (score 0):

Como você não postou o código vou fazer um exemplo

```
for($mes = 1; $mes <= 12; $mes++)
{
     $Val[] = $mes;
}

echo 'janeiro '.$Val[0];
echo 'março'.$Val[2];
```

Dessa forma o valor não vai sobrescrever, se você definir uma posição dentro do repetidor, ele vai salvar sempre na mesma posição.